# SQL Query for multiple relationships to exist in a many to many JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a many to many relationship between `Movies` and `Genres`. What I want to do is query for `Action` `Comedy` `Movies`. This is as close as I have gotten:

```
SELECT * FROM movies 
JOIN movies_genre ON (movies.id = movies_genre.movie_id) 
JOIN genres ON (movies_genre.genre_id = genres.id) 
WHERE (
  genres.genre = "Comedy" OR
  genres.genre = "Action & Adventure"
)
```

But this gives me all the movies that are Comedy or Adventure. If I change the OR to an AND then I get back an empty table. Is there a simple way to do this with one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want information about a *movie*, so `SELECT *` is not appropriate.  The following query returns movie ids that match both genres:

```
SELECT mg.movie_id
FROM movies_genre mg JOIN
     genres g
     ON mg.genre_id = g.id
WHERE g.genre IN ('Comedy', 'Action & Adventure')
GROUP BY mg.movie_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.
- `IN` is more sensible than a bunch of `OR` expressions.
- The `HAVING` clause counts the number of matching genres.  It assumes that genres are not repeated.
- If you want full movie information, you can join that in using additional logic.

Comment: The only issue is that it's possible that a movie is an Action Romance Comedy. So `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` seems better.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts . . . Look at the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```sql
select * from movies m
where m.id in (select movie_id from movies_genre join genres on (movies_genere.genre_id = genres.id) where genres.genre = 'Comedy')
and m.id in (select movie_id from movies_genre join genres on (movies_genere.genre_id = genres.id) where genres.genre = 'Action & Adventure')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works, but in no way do I believe it is the best way:

```
SELECT * FROM movies 
JOIN movies_genre ON (movies.id = movies_genre.movie_id) 
JOIN genres ON (movies_genre.genre_id = genres.id) 
WHERE (
  genres.genre = "Action"
  AND (
  movies.poster IN (
    SELECT movies.poster FROM movies 
    JOIN movies_genre ON (movies.id = movies_genre.id)
    JOIN genres ON (movies_genre.id = genres.id) 
    WHERE genres.genre = "Comedy"
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, many-to-many relationships are the worst, requiring queries like this:

```
select *
from movies as m
where exists (
    select 1
    from movies_genre as mg
    inner join genres as g
    on g.id = mg.genre_id
    where mg.movie_id = m.id
    and g.genre in ('Action & Adventure', 'Comedy')
    group by g.id
    having count(*) = 2
    )
```